# EHCache change on original element

Tags: java, ehcache

I'm using EHCache on a java project. I got a problem on this code. My object is cached at this time !

```
    Element lElem = cacheManager.get("KEY");

    if (lElem != null) {
        // Get my cached objects
        lLMyVO = (List<MyVO>) lElem.getObjectValue();
    }else{
         // Do something to set element
    }

    // Add some elements on lLMyVO list :
    for (MyVO lAnotherMyVO : lAnotherList) {
        lLMyVO .add(lMyVO );
    }
```

At this point, my `lLMyVO` list has elements of `lAnotherList` ! And that's ok. But in my EHCache object elements of `lAnotherList` are added too ! And it's not ok, I don't want to change the cache.

It seems that `lLMyVO` it's not a new object but just something like a reference to the object in cache.

Do you know the way to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default your elements will be stored as references in EHCache until, file write or other replication appears. To prevent that you can use 'copyOnWrite'/'copyOnRead' attributes in your cache configuration. So objects will be copied on your put/get operations and no mutations will be allowed.

[Ehcache documentation for reference](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/configuration#copyonread-and-copyonwrite-cache-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

(This may not be ideal solution, just giving another option)

To add to [@Alexey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57588/alexey-ogarkov)'s answer.. 
If you have only a few scenarios where mutation can occur, you can simply opt for cloning the object after retrieving from EHCache. This may save some overhead of copying it every time.

Comment: Thanks Julien for the idea. I changed configuration because I never need do change my object after reading them from ehcache.